# Blur image using Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android, xml, blur, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader and i want to blur the images.I was thinking about creating a class that i could use in xml to create the view ..something like :

```
<folder.classblur..
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/coverImageViewFavorites"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_empty_player"
       />     instead of <ImageView...
```

This is my main class (a part of it )

```
    public class Photos 
     {

     private ImageLoader imageLoader;
  private ImageView coverView;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


          imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    coverView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverImageViewFavorites);
    Track track = traksList.get(trackPosition);


        imageLoader.displayImage(track.getArtworkUrl().replace("-large", "-crop"),coverView);

 }
}
```

xml file:

```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/coverImageViewFavorites"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_empty_player"
       />
    </RelativeLayout>
```